# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Mathematics's [sixth moderator election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/6) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Jack D'Aurizio] [image: quid]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/6), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4828042769727488/0).